# Append Tuple to Two `Maybe []`

Tags: haskell

The following function appends a `tuple` to two `Maybe [a]`'s.

```
tupleToMaybeList :: (a, a) -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
tupleToMaybeList (a, b) cs ds = do
    x  <- return a
    y  <- return b
    xs <- cs
    ys <- ds
    return ((x : y : xs) ++ ys)
```

Please critique it for idiomatic Haskell-ness.

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 5):

There's a bit of redundancy in your implementation. `b <- return a` is effectively the same as `let b = a`. There's no need to “inject” pure values into a monadic context with `return`, a pure value in scope is a pure value in scope so just use `a` and `b` in place of your `x` and `y`.

The parentheses around `x : y : xs` are also technically redundant. Regardless of the ordering of the application of `x : y :` and `xs ++ ys` you'll still end up with the same list. This is *always* the case for list cons and append, if you think about it you should see why. Note that the fixity precedence for both functions is `infixr 5`.

```
prependTupleConcatMaybeLists :: (a, a) -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
prependTupleConcatMaybeLists (a, b) cs ds =
  do xs <- cs
     ys <- ds
     return $ a : b : xs ++ ys
```

I do question the necessity of writing this *particular* function. Concatenating `cs` and `ds` should probably be taken care of separately to prepending a tuple to a list. E.g.,

```
prependTupleMaybe :: (a, a) -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
prependTupleMaybe (a, b) xs = fmap (a:b:) xs

-- call site: let zs = liftA2 (++) (prependTupleMaybe pair xs) ys
-- or       : let zs = prependTupleMaybe pair (liftA2 (++) xs ys)
```